# Reading data from RS232 using phpSerial

Tags: php, serial-port

Trying to read RS232(Weighing machine) using PHP serial, i use the following code

```
$serial = new phpSerial();
$serial->deviceSet("COM1");   
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confFlowControl("none");
$serial->deviceOpen();
$read = $serial->readPort();
$data = preg_split('/\s+/', $read);
$array = array_count_values($data); 
$values = array_keys($array, max($array)); 
echo $values[0];
$serial->deviceClose();
```

I am getting response like this

> 1iAT+CMGF=1

i want actual response like string for example (**30KG**), any suggestions will be really appreciated.

source https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/phpSerial/-/php-phpserial-class-examples.html